# 18.04 LTS driver support for Nvidia RTX 2080 Ti

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, overheating

I'm currently using 18.04 LTS with NVidia 418.56 drivers, which is the latest version I see in my repository. I tried installing 430 drivers from the website directly, but my GPU was not even recognized under that.

Now the 418 drivers seems to work just fine when not under load. However when my EVGA 2080 Ti blowers are running under max load, they overheat within a minute, except the fan speed never even goes above 70%. Like, these are blower GPUs and I can't even hear them.

Do I need the newer drivers in order to support the 2080 Ti's properly? Does this also require upgrading to a 19 version of Ubuntu?

Comment: You can obtain newer drivers by adding the graphics drivers PPA. You can keep your LTS release.

Comment: I installed 430 directly from nvidia's website, but they did not work. I thought they were left out of the repository because of incompatibility issues.

Comment: No, there are no incompatibility issues. Each release only go as far as the drivers available at the time of release. Maybe some newer versions are added later but not sure. The graphics drivers PPA was created for the purpose of bringing newer versions for older releases.